# ASP.net MVC default route to show actual route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC 3 app, my default route is app/index, which mean that if a user hits "http://www.something.com", 
they are acutally seeing "http://www.something.com/app/".

However, I want to show the actual route always, which mean that when a user hits 
"http://www.something.com", I want the url in address bar to be shown as "http://www.something.com/app/". How can I achieve this?

Comment: Then you should probably be using an alias instead of a route. `url: ""` is a redirect to `url: "app/"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an redirect in your action as follows:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index(){
     return RedirectToAction("Index","App");
     // or you can do a redirect to a URL. like 301.
     return RedirectPermanent("/app");
   }

}
```